# Ubuntu linux Server 12.04.5 LTS cannot install apt-show-versions

Tags: linux, ubuntu, server, apt-get

I am running Linux Ubuntu Server 12.04.5 LTS (ubuntu-12.04.5-server-amd64)

When I tried to a `apt-get install apt-show-versions`. It says:

"Package apt-show-versions is not available"
"Package apt-show-versions has no installation candidates". How does this happen? does this mean apt-show-versions is no longer supported with apt-get? I did an `apt-get update` still the same

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 was EOLed this year in April. I would highly recommend updating to a modern LTS version.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question. I suggest deleting it and posting on [ubuntu.se].

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing *apt-get update* first.
Then, if it doesn't help, you may take a look at */etc/apt/sources.list* .
Perhaps, the repository is not set properly there.

Also, [this](https://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/allpackages) page lists *apt-show-versions* package among the others, hence, it should be available.